# Transferring information from sheet1 to sheet2 in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel

I want to send information to sheet2 from sheet1 within the same workbook. I can do it for the first and 2nd row (I just doubled the code for row 2) but I'm not sure how to display all the rows. I also need it to only display on sheet if there is a quantity (QTY) for that row on sheet1.

Here is what I have so far..any help is appreciate (beginner here).

My code here:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonl_Click()

Dim DESCRIPTION As String, PRICE As String
Worksheets("Sheetl").Select
QTY = Range("R30")
PARTNOMB = Range("J30")
DESCRIPTION = Range("N30")
PRICE = Range("Q30")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C26").Select
If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range ("C26").Offset (1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C26").End(xlDown).Select
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = QTY
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select
ActiveCell.Value = PARTNOMB
ActiveCell.offset(0, 5).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DESCRIPTION
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveCell.Value = PRICE
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
QTY = Range("R31")
PARTNUMB = Range("J31")
DESCRIPTION = Range("N31")
PRICE = Range("031")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C26").Select
If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range ("C26").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C26").End(xlDown).Select
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = QTY
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select
ActiveCell.Value = PARTNOMB
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DESCRIPTION
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveCell.Value = PRICE
```